# Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin in reportserver

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

How do I set Access-Control-Allow-Origin in reportserver?

I am using javascript to test the connection to report server but the following message is returned: (Origin *myOriginURL* not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header):

```
var invocation = new XMLHttpRequest();

function handler(evtXHR) {
    if (invocation.readyState == 4) {
        if (invocation.status == 200) {
            var tresponse = invocation.responseText;
            alert(tresponse);
        }
        else
            alert("Invocation Errors Occured" + invocation.readyState);
    }
    else {
        alert("currently the application is at" + invocation.readyState);
    } }

function TestConnection(){

 var url = tReportServerURL;

            if (invocation) {  invocation.open('GET', url, true);  invocation.onreadystatechange = handler;  invocation.send();
                }

}
```